# Javascript - Insert hyperlink in a dynamic text which is formed in javascript,and on click, it should hit a servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I have a javascript function, which has an ajax call, and on success of that call, I am appending a htm text in a div, with a dynamic variable. I want to insert a hyperlink in that dynamic variable, and on click of that hyperlink, it should hit a servlet.

```
 <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Javascript code :
On success of Ajax call :

```
success: function(resp) {
    var currentText = $("#myDiv").html(); 
    $("#myDiv").html(currentText + "Case : " + textWithLink+ " Done<BR/>"); 
}
```

I want to insert a hyperlink in 'textWithLink' and on click it should hit a servlet, say 'myServlet'.
The current output that I am getting is :
**Case ABCDEF Done**
**Case BHRTYU Done**
I want to insert hyperlink in ABCDEF and BHRTYU.
Thanks

Comment: .html("youCanIncludeHtmlTagsHere")

Comment: Simply write `$("#myDiv").html(currentText + "Case : <a href='yourservletlink'>" + textWithLink+ " </a>Done<BR/>");`